# The site's security certificate is not trusted! in Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, certificate

I'm behind my college firewall which uses a separate firewall.cer certificate. I was able to install in my firefox. So, gmail opened without any issues in firefox. But, i get the error and i'm unable to open gmail in chrome.

I have a .cer file saved. But, i don't know how to install it to chrome.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: You do understand the implications of this right? Your college can see (spy on) **everything** you send and receive on these sites, conduct MITM attacks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Certificates can be easily imported using option menu

1. Click on the Chrome Options Menu → Settings → Show advanced settings
2. Navigate to sectio HTTPS/SSL and click on Manage certificates
3. Click on Import and import your .cer file to install in your Chrome
4. Restart browser for changes to reflect.